# How to receive a json object filled up with angularjs and sent by ajax to server side (PHP)?

Tags: php, json, ajax, angularjs-scope, jsondecoder

I have the following json object:

```
$scope.sellAccessories=
 [
 {"id": "1","name": "aa", "quantity": "3","total_price": "100"}
 ,
 {"id": "2","name": "bb", "quantity": "4","total_price": "200"}
 ,
 {"id": "3","name": "cc", "quantity": "5","total_price": "300"}
];
```

i sent the object using ajax as follow:

```
var options={
    type : "get",
    url : "../php/sell.php",
    data: {"function":"sellAccess","data":$scope.sellAccessories},
    dataType: 'json',
    async : false,
    cache : false,
    success : function(response,status){
        alert("success")
    },
    error:function(request,response,error){
        alert("error")
    }
};
$.ajax(options);
```

I tried to receive the data using **$_GET['name']** but it didn't work

My php code:

$item_name=json_decode($_GET['name']);

i also, tried to do:
$data=json_decode($_GET['data']);

but none of them works!

thanks in advance

Comment: use json $json = json_decode($url,true); then access $id = $json['id'][0];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to retrieve the data based on the url query. So for example if you need the JSON data then you would retrieve the JSON by doing

`$jsonData = $_GET['data'];`

Then you would have to process this JSON object and you can make it an array by using the PHP function `json_decode` like so

`$arrayData = json_decode($jsonData, true);`

Then you can traverse said data, as any other array.

Comment: so whats wrong in this?
`$jsonData = $_GET['data'];`
`$arrayData = json_decode($jsonData, true);`

`$item_id=$_GET['id'];`
`file_put_contents("hell.txt", $item_id);`

Comment: Where is $_GET['id'] defined? You don't use the $_GET variable to traverse arrays. I would highly suggest you read up on [this on PHP arrays.](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp)

Comment: oh sorry i meant this:
`$item_id=$arrayData[0]['id'];`
`file_put_contents("hell.txt", $item_id);`

Comment: What's the issue with that? That should result in 1. Did you remember to add `true` as the second parameter to the `json_decode` so it becomes an associative array

Comment: yes, i surely did :S, maybe the problem from the js side? since i am sending the data in the ajax in this for: `{"function":"sellAccess","data":$scope.sellAccessories}`

Comment: Try from within your PHP server, to dump the array using `var_dump($jsonData)` and then doing it again after the conversion to the associative array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170605/discussion-between-classified-and-aly-al-ameen).